# How to display levels dynamically?

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, jquery, app-development

[image]

Hi,
Here i want to select level according to that level below rows will appear like if i select level 1 row will select if level is 2 show 2 rows level1 and level2?

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity">
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.BucketRateCss}"/>

<apex:sectionHeader title="opportunity Edit" subtitle="{!opportunity.name}"/>
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="opportunity Edit" mode="edit">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" action="{!save}" />
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
 <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" action="{!save}" />
 <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information" columns="2">
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Name}" required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.OwnerId}" required="false"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.LeadSource}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}" required="true"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Amount}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.StageName}" required="true"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Probability}" required="false"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Type}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Description}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NextStep}" required="false"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contract Information" columns="2">
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Advance_Rate__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Discount_Federal_Express_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Invoice_Processing_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Discount_TripPak_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Funding_Type__c}" id="type" onchange="fund(this)"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Bank_Wire_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.X60_Minute_Funding__c}" html-class="percentage" required="false" id="id5"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.TransCheck_Transaction_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.X60_Minute_Funding_Amt__c}" html-class="dollor"  required="false" id="id1"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Fuel_Transaction_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.X3_Hour_Funding_1__c}" html-class="percentage" required="false" id="id6"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Online_BillPay__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.X3_Hour_Funding_Amt__c}" html-class="dollor" required="false" id="id2" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Monthly_Minimum_Invoice_Volume__c}" required="false"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Same_Day_Funding_1__c}" html-class="percentage" required="false" id="id8"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reserve_Release_Days__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.Same_Day_Funding_Amt__c}" html-class="dollor" required="false" id="id4"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Agreement_Term__c}" required="false"/> 
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Next_Day_Funding_Perc__c}" html-class="percentage" required="false" id="id7"/>             
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.WealthBuilder_Rebates__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputText value="{!opportunity.Next_Day_Funding__c}" html-class="dollor" required="false" id="id3"/> 
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Administrative_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Administrative_Fee_Amt__c}" required="false"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NBT_Fuel_Advance_Rate__c}" required="false"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Client_Contribution_Rate__c}" required="false"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NBT_Fuel_Advance_Fee_1__c}" required="false"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NBT_Contribution_Rate__c}" required="false"/> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.NBT_Fuel_Advance_Fee_per_1000__c}" required="false"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Cash_Management_Rebates__c}" required="false"/> 
     <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Charge_back_Days__c}" required="false"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Flat_Rate_Factoring_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Daily_Rate_Factoring_Fee__c}" required="false"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>


    <div class="containerbucket">
  <div class="content">
  <div class="leftcontent">
  <div class="brate">Bucket Rate</div>
  <p style="=float:left;">
  <input id="Yes" type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes" onClick="yesclick()"/>
    Yes  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input id="No" type="radio" name="Yes" value="No" onClick="noclick()"/>
    No </p>
   </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div id="row2" style="display:none">
  <div class="leftcontent2">
   <div class="bratelevels">Bucket Rate Levels <br />
    <br />
    Level 1 <br />
    Level 2<br />
    Level 3<br />
    Level 4 </div>
  <div class="rightcontent">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <table>
     <tr style="background-color:#808080;">
      <th>Low Days</th>
      <th>High Days</th>
      <th>Level Fee</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.High_Days__c}"/></td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Level_Fee__c}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Low_Days__c}"/></td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.High_Days__c}"/></td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Level_Fee__c}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Low_Days__c}"/></td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.High_Days__c}"/></td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Level_Fee__c}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Low_Days__c}"/></td>
       <td>90</td>
      <td><apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Level_Fee__c}"/></td>

    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
 </div>        
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Fields" columns="1"> 
  <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Addendum__c}" required="false"/> 
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock> 
   </apex:form> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

           function changeDisplay(type, show){
      j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

 if(show){
    j$(type).show();
    j$(type).each(function(){
        j$("label[for='" + this.id + "']").show();
    });
  } else {
  j$(type).hide();
    j$(type).each(function(){
        j$("label[for='" + this.id + "']").hide();
     });
   }
 } 

 function fund(s){

   if(s.value == "$"){
    changeDisplay(".dollor", true);
     changeDisplay(".percentage", false);
    }else
    if(s.value =='%'){
     changeDisplay(".dollor", false);
    changeDisplay(".percentage", true);
   }else{
    changeDisplay(".dollor", true);
    changeDisplay(".percentage", true);
   }
 }
            </script>

  <!--BUCKET RATE-->

<script type="text/javascript">

  function yesclick()
 {
  document.getElementById("row2").style.display = "block";
 }
 function noclick()
 {
  document.getElementById("row2").style.display = "none";
 }

  </script>

 </apex:page>
```

Comment: There's a JQuery plug-in called DataTables that might do what you want which is not totally clear to me. You can find it on the list of plug-ins on the JQuery web site.

Comment: You might get more help if you reduce the amount of code. It looks like everything above the Bucket Rate stuff is irrelevant to the issue. Those 50 or so input fields just get in the way of understanding the problem.